# using a symmetric matrix to simplify expression involving antisymmetric matrices

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, cross-product

I am trying to simplify the following expression --$$(\vec{A} \times \vec{B})\cdot\underline{\underline{S}}\cdot(\vec{C} \times \vec{D}) = (A_jB_k\epsilon_{jki})S_{im}(\epsilon_{mnp}C_nD_p)$$
$S$ is a symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix, $\epsilon$ is the antisymmetric tensor object.

Can one get rid of the $\epsilon$-s somehow using the symmetry of the matrix $S$?

Comment: I assume the dimension of the underlying vector space is $3$?

Comment: yes it is 3. any more edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't use the symmetry of $S$, but you can use the following identity:

$$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{mnp}=\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}\delta_{kp}+\delta_{in}\delta_{jp}\delta_{km}+\delta_{ip}\delta_{jm}\delta_{kn}-\delta_{im}\delta_{jp}\delta_{kn}-\delta_{ip}\delta_{jn}\delta_{km}-\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}\delta_{kp}$$

to get

$$(A \times B)\cdot S\cdot(C \times D) = \text{tr}(S)\left[(A\cdot C)(B\cdot D)-(A\cdot D)(B\cdot C)\right]-(A\cdot C)(B\cdot S\cdot D)-(A\cdot S\cdot C)(B\cdot D)+(A\cdot D)(B\cdot S\cdot C)+(A\cdot S\cdot D)(B\cdot C).$$

Have fun with that!

(Note that the identity given above is just a more fundamental version of the (more commonly taught) identity

$$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{inp}=\delta_{jn}\delta_{kp}-\delta_{nk}\delta_{jp}$$
which you can derive from the above identity by contracting on $i$ and $m$)

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! I am mentally kicking myself for not thinking of this identity earlier. :)